# Parse json file with variable length in Swift

Tags: json, swift, xcode, api, parsing

I want to parse a json file from an API. I get this json from API (just an example, I can poll for whatever coins I like):

```
{
  "ethereum": {
    "usd": 3228.32,
    "usd_market_cap": 378715635680.9308,
    "usd_24h_vol": 20454034072.297222,
    "usd_24h_change": -0.0033300457476910226,
    "last_updated_at": 1629930233
  },
  "bitcoin": {
    "usd": 49100,
    "usd_market_cap": 923292263228.3533,
    "usd_24h_vol": 33433401406.230736,
    "usd_24h_change": 1.4329298489913256,
    "last_updated_at": 1629930192
  }
}
```

So I made two structures to match the json:

```
struct Coindata: Codable {
    var bitcoin: Price?
    var ethereum: Price?
}

struct Price: Codable {
    var usd: Double?
    var usd_market_cap: Double?
    var usd_24h_vol: Double?
    var usd_24h_change: Double?
    var last_updated_at: Int?
}
```

The above works fine and I can read out the different fields. But I don't want it to be a fixed set of coins and write a new member in "Coindata" struct for every coin I want to poll. Is there a good way to make this dynamic? For example a function that takes in string of array where I can write the coins I want. something like this:

```
array = ["bitcoin","ethereum","cardano","tether"]
pollCoinData(array)
```

I am doing this to parse:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let coinData = try decoder.decode(Coindata.self, from: data!)
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: @ElTomato That wasn't very helpful, what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than having a `CoinData` struct, you can decode a *dictionary* with the cryptocurrencies' names as the keys, and `Price` objects as the values.

```
let coinData = try decoder.decode([String: Price].self, from: data!)
```

Now to get the `Price` for Bitcoin for example, you can just do:

```
if let bitcoinPrice = coinData["bitcoin"] {
    // ...
} else {
    // there is no price info about bitcoin in the JSON!
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you! appreciate it